# The javascript for the time increases it's speed on the second loop

Tags: javascript, reload

Help me debug this code. The button should open a link onclick and the visit button on the main page will be disabled and it's value will become a timer. There's no problem on first click, but when the timer runs out and I click the button again, the speed of the clock increases. Please help me.

```
<html>
<head>
    <script type = "text/javascript">

    var t;
    var isTimeron = false;
    var counter = 0;
    function disableButt()
    {

    document.getElementById("but1").disabled = true;

    }

    function enableVisit()
    {
        document.getElementById("but1").disabled = false;
    }   

    function stopMe()
    {
        isTimeron = false;
            clearTimeout(t);

    }

    function countdown()
    {
        document.getElementById("but1").value = counter;
        counter--;
        if (counter <= -1)
        {
        stopMe();
        document.getElementById("but1").value = "VISIT";
        document.getElementById("but1").disabled = false;
        enableVisit();
        }
        t = setTimeout("countdown();", 1000);
    }

    function startMe()  {
        if (!isTimeron)
        {
            counter = 10;
            isTimeron = true;
            countdown();    

        }

    }



     </script>
<body>

<a href='' target = '_blank'><input type = "button" id = "but1" value = "VISIT" style="background:#83FF59; font-weight:bold;"
    onclick = "startMe(); disableButt();"/></a>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: also is there a way wherein the button color will change to gray when it's already inactive?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not stopping the first timer.

```
function countdown()
{
    document.getElementById("but1").value = counter;
    counter--;
    if (counter <= -1)
    {
    stopMe();
    document.getElementById("but1").value = "VISIT";
    document.getElementById("but1").disabled = false;
    enableVisit();
    }
    t = setTimeout("countdown();", 1000);
}
```

The counter goes under zero, you call stopMe() by you still call setTimeout. You have two timer going on now.

Just change it to

```
function countdown()
{
    document.getElementById("but1").value = counter;
    counter--;
    if (counter <= -1)
    {
    stopMe();
    document.getElementById("but1").value = "VISIT";
    document.getElementById("but1").disabled = false;
    enableVisit();
    return;
    }
    t = setTimeout("countdown();", 1000);
}
```

Small suggestion avoid strings in setTimeout.

```
setTimout(countdown, 1000);
```

is better

Comment: @b3m475 does it mean that the 'return;' will terminate the function called? sorry im new at javascript programming and learning on my own so you know, sorry :)

Comment: @melvinmanangan the return statement ends the function execution (as in all the other languages ;-)). In this particular case if you omit it the if statement ends and the setTimout is called in all the cases.

Comment: no im fine for now, :)) thanks for your help, is there anything i can do to return the favor? :)

Comment: hey by the way, i want to ask one more help, can you teach me a technique so that the timer will not reset when i refresh or reload the page? :(

Comment: if the browser supports localStorage you can save in it the current timestamp at each tick and when the page is loaded use that to understand of how much time has passed since the last executed tick, https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage